# installation for some modules are not completing

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-3.11

```
PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\khurram> pip install turtle
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-p9y4gakw\turtle_c9e4338b26474ea7b22fce8c06a69ff1\setup.py", line 40
          except ValueError, ve:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

i have been trying to get rid of this problem since two weeks but the results are nothing.i tried every possible way of changing path,virtual environment and others way which i have seen on internet please help me to sort out this problem

Comment: Why do you install [package from 2009](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/)? `turtle` is [part of Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).

Comment: Which Python version are you actually using? 2.7 or 3.11?

Comment: @buran actually i want to make some animations with the help of turtle

Comment: @mkrieger1 im using 3.11

Comment: i just want to download any module which can help me to make animations or graphics which can give me pleasure with my programming journey as a begginer.

Comment: The old `turtle` package you try to install is, according to description _Turtle is an HTTP proxy whose purpose is to throttle connections to specific hostnames to avoid breaking terms of usage of those API providers_ you probably want [pythonturtle](https://pypi.org/project/PythonTurtle/) if not the module from Standard Library which I mentioned in my first comment. I would go for the module from Standard Library